# Browser geolocation: Determining previous permissions

Tags: html, browser, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

Ok so I've got code like the following:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
    function (e) {
        alert('ok');
    }, function (e) {
        alert('denied');
    } 
);
```

I could call this on pageload, and if the permission is denied, I'll hide the buttons and functionality that rely on having geoloc information.

However, I don't want to request the permission on pageload, but only on demand, when a user chooses to click one of the geoloc buttons.

So in this scenario, supposing that a user arrives on my page, having previously decided to deny access to the geolocation API, is it possible to tell that the permission has been previously denied so that I can hide the buttons without having to wait until they click one of the buttons again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean denied access to another website, or previously on your website?

If the former, why assume you are subject to that decision? That is, don't worry about it and ask again anyway.

If the latter, you probably ought to store the decision for the duration of the user's session on your site. You could do this server-side if you are using server sessions, or with simple cookies.

Comment: The latter ... with a cookie solution, it would lessen the problem, but it would still be there if the decision as stored in the browser outlives the decision as stored in the cookie.

Comment: Am accepting this answer as it's the first one posted.
It seems like an omission of the spec that querying permissions is conflated with prompting for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result in the browser, for example using LocalStorage or cookies. However if the user denied access the first time doesn't mean he will do so next time. But if you hide or disable the buttons he can't use the functionality even if he wanted to. Now if he denies 10 times in a row, or some number like that, that would make more sense.

Comment: Testing using Chrome: the first call to `getCurrentPosition` pops up the permissions dialog to explicitly ask the user.  Subsequent calls silently deny the permission, so the user is not given an opportunity to change her decision anyway.

Comment: Different browsers means different client side behaviors here. And even with Chrome the user can go into settings and reset the permissions to get prompted again.

Comment: Yes, and I also noticed Chrome puts a little icon on the right hand side of the location bar which gives direct access to this setting.

Comment: The problem is still that if a user subsequently clicks a button after previously denying the permission, there is no re-prompt for the permission.

Comment: Try using IE or FireFox (or an iPad for that matter)